# Early binding of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WordBasic call in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, com, ms-word, late-binding

I'm trying to call this code in VB.NET with "option strict on":

```
Dim application As word.Application = New word.Application
application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros(1)
```

The WordBasic object is dynamic, there is no type library available.
Now the compiler will complain, because late binding is not allowed.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that got borken in vb.net since VS2008, a victim of the Linq and Option Infer powerhouses.

Making it early bound is too tricky, there are too many versions of VBA floating around.  Notable is that I couldn't get Reflection working, which would normally be the early bound way to do late binding :)  Best thing to do is put this code in a separate source code file so you can compile that with Option Strict Off in effect.

Comment: I've thought about using reflection, and srangely, it doesn't seem to work for anyone. Thanks for the solution!